# How to stop Intel icpc complaining undefined reference to basic_string?

Tags: c++, icc

I'm trying to compile a very simple program using Intel `icpc` on MacOS.

```cpp
// File: test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s = "hello";
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The command `icpc -O2 -o test test.cpp` outputs

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEC1Emc", referenced from:
      _main in icpcDe7qot.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I tried with `icpc -O2 -o test test.cpp /usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib` but it returned the same error message.
However, using `g++` or `clang++` works fine.

The version of `icpc` is `icpc version 19.0.5.281 (gcc version 4.9.0 compatibility)`.

The version of `xcode` is

```
Xcode 11.2.1
Build version 11B500
```

The version of MacOS is `10.15.1 (19B88)`

Could someone please tell me how to correctly link the library?

Comment: Looks like something's wrong with your icpc... haven't seen this issue before...